# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namedtuple_as_object'

Tags: python, json, django, django-templates, typeerror

Not really sure what is going on here. I got an error during template rendering.

This is a snippet of the html files code:

```
{% load jsonify %}
{% for geofence in geofences.all %}
           <tr>
               <td>{{ geofence.geofence_name }}</td>
               <td>{{ geofence.location }}</td>
               <td>{{ geofence.addressLineOne }}</td>    
               <td>{{ geofence.radius }} meters</td>
               <td><span id="confirm_delete_{{ geofence.gimbal_id }}" class="confirm_delete"><a class="close_x_red_small" href="#" onclick="CancelDelete(); return false;"></a><em></em><a class="delete_button" href="{% url 'geofence_manager_delete' geofence.gimbal_id %}">Delete</a><ol></ol></span><a class="trash_sm" title="Delete &quot;{{ geofence.geofence_name }}&quot; Geofence" onclick="ConfirmDelete('{{ geofence.gimbal_id }}', '{{ geofence.geofence_name|jsonify }}'); return false;" href="#"></a></td>         
           </tr>
                              {% empty %}
           <tr>
                  <td colspan="7">You currently have no Geofences.</td>
           /tr> 
     {% endfor %}
```

In the traceback, the part that is showing an error is: `{{ geofence.geofence_name|jsonify }}`

I think there is a problem with jsonify, but what exactly could it be? No errors occurred previous to that. Can someone shed some light on this? I can can provide information if needed.

**Edit:**

Models as requested:

```
class Geofence(models.Model):

    geofence_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    addressLineOne = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    radius = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(3000),MinValueValidator(50)])
    latitude = models.FloatField('latitude', blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField('longitude', blank=True, null=True)
    gimbal_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default=0)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.geofence_name
```

Comment: what does your model look like?

Comment: I have added my model in OP.